# How to do placements of lists and how to fill contents in it?

Tags: java, list, frame

I am making a simple calculator program, in which I have used buttons textfields and lists. The button and textFields are placed properly on the screen but the list is not. Please help me to place the list in the desired position on the screen and also tell me how to fill its contents.

```
    import java.math.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    public class fc2 extends Frame implements ActionListener
    {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
     fc2 f=new fc2();
     f.setSize(500,400);
     f.setVisible(true);
     f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        }
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e)
    { }
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e)
    { }
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
    { }
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e)
    { }
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e)
    { }
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e)
    { }
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
    {
     System.exit(0);
    }
    public  fc2()
    {
    buttonexit=new Button("Exit");
    textField1=new TextField("BASIC CALCULATOR");
    textField1.setEditable(false);
    value1=new TextField(6);
    value2=new TextField(6);
    v1=new TextField("Value 1");
    v2=new TextField("Value 2");
    v1.setEditable(false);
    v2.setEditable(false);
    plus=new Button("  +  ");
    minus=new Button("  -  ");
    divide=new Button("  /  ");
    multiply=new Button("  *  ");
    answer=new TextField(10);
    a1=new TextField("Answer");
    a1.setEditable(false);
    answer.setEditable(false);
    add(textField1);
    add(value1);
    add(value2);
    List l1=new List(4);
    l1.setBounds(100,100,100,10);
    add(l1);
    add(v1);
    buttonexit.addActionListener(this);
    plus.addActionListener(this);
    minus.addActionListener(this);
    divide.addActionListener(this);
    multiply.addActionListener(this);
    add(v2);
    add(plus);
    add(minus);
    add(divide);
    add(multiply);
    add(answer);
    add(a1);
    add(buttonexit);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
     textField1.setLocation(175,60);
     v1.setLocation(80,100);
     v2.setLocation(320,100);
     value1.setLocation(84,125);
     value2.setLocation(324,125);
     plus.setLocation(107,210);
     minus.setLocation(177,210);
     multiply.setLocation(247,210);
     divide.setLocation(317,210);
     a1.setLocation(195,320);
     answer.setLocation(180,350);
     buttonexit.setLocation(350,350);
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
    if(e.getSource()==plus)
    {
     double a=Double.valueOf(value1.getText());
     double b=Double.valueOf(value2.getText());
     double c=a+b;
     double d=c*10000;
     double m=Math.floor(d);
     double f=m/10000;
     String str=String.valueOf(f);
     answer.setText(str);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==minus)
    {
     double a=Double.valueOf(value1.getText());
     double b=Double.valueOf(value2.getText());
     double c=a-b;
     double d=c*10000;
     double m=Math.floor(d);
     double f=m/10000;
     String str=String.valueOf(f);
     answer.setText(str);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==multiply)
    {
     double a=Double.valueOf(value1.getText());
     double b=Double.valueOf(value2.getText());
     double c=a*b;
     double d=c*10000;
     double m=Math.floor(d);
     double f=m/10000;
     String str=String.valueOf(f);
     answer.setText(str);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==divide)
    {
     double a=Double.valueOf(value1.getText());
     double b=Double.valueOf(value2.getText());
     String str;
     if(b==0)
     {
      str=("Not Possible");
     }
     else
     {
      double c=a/b;
      double d=c*10000;
      double m=Math.floor(d);
      double f=m/10000;
      str=String.valueOf(f);
     }
     answer.setText(str);
    }
    if(e.getSource()==buttonexit)
    {
     System. exit(0);
    }
   }
   Button plus,minus,divide,multiply,buttonexit;
   TextField textField1,value1,value2,v1,v2,a1,answer;
   List l1;
}
```

Comment: How does it look like now, and how should it look like?

Comment: I am unable to make placements of lists Even if I use set  Bound or Set Location it does not works So is there any other alternative